# ngx-image-cropper style not wroking

Tags: css, angular

I used my angular 6 project for the [ngx-image-cropper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper) that one is working fine, I try to change that cropper style but its not a change , any one know how to do that correctly

I used this style

```
.cropper .move {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: move;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add style in parent component (index.html) OR global CSS (styles.css) with the important attribute.

**index.html**

```
.cropper .move 
{
  width: 100%;
  cursor: move;
  border: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

Comment: Wc, glad to help you.

Comment: DO you have any solution if I zoom image want to select upper part of image so I can drag image, do you have any solution ? please help